# Excel - combination of ISNUMBER(SEARCH()) with CONCATENATE() function

Tags: excel, search

I would like to use the following formulas:

```
   =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("March", B582)),CONCATENATE(MIN(D582:INDIRECT("D"&L582))," - ",MAX(D582:INDIRECT("D"&L582))," ",E582;",",F582),CONCATENATE(",",C582,",",F582))
```

and

```
  =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("March", B582)),COUNTIF(I$1:I$1080; ""& I582),1)
```

according to:

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/10/22/excel-if-wildcard-statement/

and

https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text

Why am I getting an error then?

[image]

Is there any chance to execute the text-based condition in the form like this without inserting a new column?

Comment: I looks like both formulas have errant semi-colons, after E582 in the first formula and I$1080 in the second.

Comment: OK, I've removed them but it's still the same.

Comment: My mistake. I left off the part about them needing to be commas,

Comment: So concluding, what is wrong with my formulas?

Comment: The semi-colon in each should be a comma,

Comment: yes, now it's fine thanks